# PYTHON - reading single row from a file

Tags: python, io

I'm hours new to python, and I'm trying to write a script which reads a set of x,y coordinates from a file (named 'peaks.dat') and fills them into a list (of class type); I'm defining the following:

```
class point():
    def _init_(self,x=None,y=None,k=None,f=None):
        self.x=0    # x coordinate
        self.y=0    # y coordinate
        self.k=0    # I need these for later stuff
        self.f=-1   # I need these for later stuff
```

But then I couldn't find any way to "pick" a single element from a line (namely, an element from only one of the two columns) in the file, instead of the whole line. Is there such a thing?

Regardless, I tried splitting my columns into two different files x.dat and y.dat, but then I quite don't know how to separately fill my 'point' type list's x and y fields from the files.
I tried

```
f=open('x.dat','r')
mylist=[]
for line in f:
    mylist.append(point(line, , , )) # wrong syntax D:
f.close()

for data in mylist:
    print i.x
```

planning to to the same later for the y.dat file, but it seems to be wrong on many levels.

p.s. I come from some C++, if you want to give examples.

edit: peaks.dat is just three columns (I only need the first two) of numbers, something like

```
1.2   1.6   0.4
1.5   2.1   0.3
1.1   1.0   0.5
```

etc.

x.dat (or y.dat) is a single row of numbers.

Comment: It would help to see what the line looks like. You can split a string using `"string here".split("char to split by")` to get a list of strings, which you can then convert to int.

Comment: Post a small sample of `x.dat`.

Comment: the peaks.dat file is something like <some number> - tabulation - <some other number> endline; and so on for n lines; I'll look up your split thingy now.

Comment: Did you properly copy the indents  from your real code? If not, please fix them

Comment: FWIW, `_init_` needs to be `__init__`.

Comment: YOu can use the `with` statement to make your code cleaner and safer! [Check it out!](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.split` to split the data on a line, `str.split` returns a list of string.

Examples:

```
>>> strs = "1.2   1.6   0.4"
>>> strs.split()
['1.2', '1.6', '0.4']
#use slicing as you need only first two items
>>> [float(x) for x in strs.split()[:2]] 
[1.2, 1.6]
```

If you want only the first two columns from each line:

```
mylist=[]
with open('x.dat') as f:
   for line in f:
       #apply int to the items of `str.split` to convert them into integers
       x, y = [float(z) for z in line.split()[:2]]
       mylist.append(Point(x, y))
```

If you wanted to read only first two rows:

```
mylist=[]
with open('x.dat') as f:
   rows = 2
   for _ in xrange(rows):
       line = next(f)
       x, y, k = [float(z) for z in line.split()]
       mylist.append(Point(x, y, k))
```

Some changes to your class  definition:

```
class point():
   def __init__(self,x = None,y =None,k =None,f =None):
      self.x = 0 if x is None else x  #assign default value only if the value was not passed
      self.y = 0 if y is None else y
      self.k = 0 if k is None else k
      self.f = -1 if f is None else f
```

Comment: Ok this is the one I understood the most, but won't my script complain if I fill him two arguments (x,y) in instead of four?

Comment: @Tom No, it won't. As we're using default values for them.

Comment: @Tom but this only includes 2 COLUMNS and not ROWS as stated above :o

Comment: @user2033511 I guess I misread the specs, added row related answer as well.

Comment: @user2033511 Oh damn I screwed up big time, I'll fix my question right away!

Comment: `self.x = 0 if x is None else x` can be written much shorter, and less prone to copy-paste errors: `self.x = x or 0`.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the format of the file, you either want to use the `csv` module, or use the `str.split()` function.

For whitespace-separated values on a line, use `str.split()`:

```
points = []

with open(inputfilename) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        row = [int(i) for i in line.split()]
        # row is now a list of integers.
        points.append(point(*row))
```

For other formats, usually the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) is the best option:

```
import csv

points = []

with open(inputfilename, 'rb') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t')  # tab delimited file
    for row in reader:
        row = [int(i) for i in row]
        # row is now a list of integers.
        points.append(point(*row))
```

To read only two lines, use `next()` twice; csv version:

```
    for _ in range(2):
        row = [int(i) for i in next(reader)]
        # row is now a list of integers.
        points.append(point(*row))
```

`next()` takes the next item from an iterator; both the `infile` object and the `reader` object are iterators that yield file lines or CSV rows.

Alternatively, use the [`itertools.islice()` utility](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
for row in islice(reader, 2):  # only yield the first two rows.
```

Comment: I really like `map(int, row)` :D Anyways, imho the best answer.

Comment: @user2033511: `map()` returns an iterator on Python 3, which can be surprising to new programmers. Without a Python version in the OP, I stuck to something that is easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the format of your files. Are the coordinates separated by commas?
If so, then.

```
with open('x.dat','r') as f:
    mylist=[]
    for line in f:
        points = line.split(",")
        mylist.append(point(int(points[0]), int(points[1]), int(points[2]),int(points[3])))
```

I'm sure there's a nicer and more pythonic way to do this.

You can read about Python's 'with' here
http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

Maybe you can find something useful here, http://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#module-io if my answer wasn't what you were looking for.

Comment: If they're comma-separated, he should use `csv`, not `str.split`